# CSS div class selection

Tags: css, css-selectors

I downloaded a framework and they are using this as a css selector:

```
#Footer .footerTop
```

Why not just use:

```
.footerTop
```

Are they the same, or selection is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#Footer .footerTop` only applies to the `.footerTop` within `#Footer`

```
<div id="Footer">
  <div class="footerTop">I qualify</div>
</div>
<div id="Copyright">
  <div class="footerTop">I don't qualify</div>
</div>
```

Using just `.footerTop` would apply rules to both of the inner `DIV` elements, losing its specificity.

Answer (score 0):

`#` is an **[id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)** and `.` is a [**class selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

So they are selecting an element with class footerTop inside an element with id Footer.